# MS Exchange Server SMTP name for PowerShell script

Tags: powershell

If I wamted to send an email from a recently migrated MS Outlook account on MS Exchange Server to a MS Hotmail account on IMAP using PowerShell 5 like this:

```
$splatr = @{
To = 'her@hotmail.com' 
From = 'him@outlook.com'
Subject ='test'
Body ='test'
SmtpServer ='??????'
Port = 587
UseSSL = $true
}
Send-MailMessage @splatr -Credential him@outlook.com
```

where would I get the Outlook/Exchange Server SMTP name from, please?

If it were the other way around, I would use

```
SmtpServer ='smtp-mail.outlook.com'
```

Thank you.

Comment: Give the IP Address of your exchange server where the SMTP has been configured. By default it  uses port 25 else you have to pass the port as a parameter like -Port

Comment: Thank you, Ranadip. I can easily change the 587 to 25, but where would I get the IP address of the SMTP Exchange server, please?

Comment: You are asking us what the address of your Exchange server is?

Comment: from outlook, 

Start Microsoft Outlook.

Click the "File" tab on the ribbon and then click "Info."

Click the "Account Settings" button and then select "Account Settings."

Select the account for which you want to look up the SMTP information and then click the "Change" button.

Look in the field next to "Outgoing Mail Server (SMTP)" to determine what SMTP server your email account is using.

Click the "Cancel" button to return to the main Outlook window.

Comment: Type "nslookup". 
Your computer's DNS Server name and IP address will be displayed. 
Type "set type=mx" - This will cause NSLOOKUP to only return what are known as MX (Mail eXchange) records from the DNS servers. 
For an example, type "hotmail.com" or use your own domain name.

Comment: This is what I get, thank you:

Comment: PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> cd\
PS C:\> nslookup
Default Server:  UnKnown
Address:  192.168.1.1

> outlook.com
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  192.168.1.1

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    outlook.com
Addresses:  40.97.160.2
          40.97.164.146
          40.97.156.114
          40.97.155.26
          40.97.113.210
          40.97.166.138
          40.97.153.146
          40.97.113.34
          40.96.32.50
          40.97.170.154

>

Comment: Seeing this, I believe you do not have a valid SMTP server configured in your domain. may be you are using Google SMTP or offiice365 or might be some other smtp server. 

Refer the answer which I have submitted. may be you can get it from outlook. Hope that helps you.

Answer (score 0):

**From Outlook,**

- Start Microsoft Outlook.
- Click the "File" tab on the ribbon and then click "Info."
- Click the "Account Settings" button and then select "Account Settings."
- Select the account for which you want to look up the SMTP information and then click the "Change" button.
- Look in the field next to "Outgoing Mail Server (SMTP)" to determine what SMTP server your email account is using.
- Click the "Cancel" button to return to the main Outlook window.

**Alternative;**

- Type "nslookup".  Your computer's DNS Server name and IP address will
  be displayed.
- Type "set type=mx" - This will cause NSLOOKUP to only return what are
  known as MX (Mail eXchange) records from the DNS servers.  For an
  example, type "hotmail.com" or use your own domain name.